# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table ruby on rails includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, include

Query is

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(:id=>post_ids).select("posts.id,posts.title, posts.description,posts.vote").group('posts.id').order("(count(distinct comments.id)) desc")
```

It gives an error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "comments"`

Comment: Show us your `schema.rb` file

Comment: has_many relation between post and comments

Comment: I would guess that you're missing a `post_id` in your comments table.

Comment: Can you put your models definition, the sql statement executed as shown in the log and the database tables definition?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `includes` to `joins`. because if you have not condition by related model it will be loaded in separate query. `Joins` always use single query.